# Does this shorthand for background removes the other attributes?

Tags: css, background, shorthand

If I have:

```
background:#A2A2A2 url('./images/img.png') repeat-x left bottom;
```

and then I use:

```
background:#000000; /* not to confuse with 'background-color' */
```

**Do `background-image`,`background-repeat` and `background-position` are lost?**

Comment: If your second line is not setting `background-color`, what is it setting?

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: It *is* setting `background-color`. The comment is cautioning the reader not to confuse the shorthand `background` property with the `background-color` property.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff, it is indeed setting background-color, but it is doing more than just changing the bg-color

Comment: @ajax333221 I guess I'm asking: Why not use `background-color` so it doesn't overwrite the other properties? But I guess your question isn't asking how to solve that problem, just whether it overwrites them.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff actually, I was actually hoping it removes the other properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`background-image`, `background-repeat` *and* `background-position` (among other things) will be implicitly set to their default values when you leave them out in the shorthand property. It's just how a shorthand property works (for the most part).

The computed background styles end up looking something like this:

```
background-color: #000000;  /* Your specified value */
background-image: none;     /* Default value */
background-repeat: repeat;  /* Default value */
background-position: 0% 0%; /* Default value */
```

So yes, those values you set in the first shorthand declaration will be lost.

Comment: He is the CSS master... He knows what you're asking before you've asked it.

Comment: I am curious about that "(among other things)", what else properties will be lost?

Comment: @ajax333221: There's also `background-attachment` in CSS2, and a number of others in CSS3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background