# How can I override only the second image in a multiple background image declaration?

Tags: css, background-image

How can I utilize the cascade to override only the second image in a multiple background image declaration?

I have specified a standard style for `li`s, with two background images (the kitten, and the fish on the right side).  I've also specified a style for `li.secondary` where I want to change only the second of the two background images:

```css
li { 
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAAeCAYAAAA/xX6fAAAA/ElEQVR42q2WYQ3DIBSE5wAJk1AJSKiESpiESakEJCChEpAwCW/vJSw0LPQoHMn3A0q5R7leeIjIFNo2JSm+Zz5DSAy6oLan8lKiIjV5fGu8u+TnrkfIKftpUQGks3Au8qNE6yOx1Sb/xPJYyH3EURW4QsHGZ5NB3K0dDpDwDvEZysAZvvP4znVpwTVcmrAgLsLX/yXhP+xfrOyuza00sbFZ7p5TAGlyYMF/J4axNClOvKKVJnEmTa6gpgkSM0Ca8HdITxOiSwuzLjVoAUAUxIWQBXESMQTpSWQd4r0GuxiJsZPII0F6EnUZg5hES7dZWEkExPj3GiDCv9d8AVEGli2R88rKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat-y 90% center,
  #CCC url("http://placekitten.com/275/300") repeat right center;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }

li.secondary {
  background: #CCC url("http://placekitten.com/325/300") repeat left 10%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KatieK/9zcnp/1/

But the new declaration for `background:` blows out the first background image (the fish).  How can I address only the second background image in a cascading rule?

Comment: include the fish in the .secondary??

Comment: Yeah, I've been having to re-specify the fish in `.secondary`.  But I figured I ought to be able to use the *cascade* part of CSS.  ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way the cascade works makes it impossible to override individual background layers without repeating the rest of the layers in each declaration.

In general, the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) works on a per-declaration basis, where each [declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#declaration) consists of exactly one property and one value:

```css
/* Declaration */
property: value;
```

A comma-separated list of background layers counts as a single value for the purposes of the cascade, which is why your second `background` declaration completely overrides the first.<sup>1</sup>

While `background` is a shorthand for several other properties, it is not a shorthand for individual background layers, as they do not have their own properties. Since individual layer properties don't exist, you cannot use the cascade to override only certain layers while keeping the rest.<sup>2</sup>

This is also why prefixed gradients in layered backgrounds are so verbose and repetitive. Sadly for us, this is a limitation of the CSS syntax, so not much can be done to improve or work around it using CSS alone.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is similar to why a shorthand declaration like `background: #ccc` will delete an image that was previously declared using `background-image` (examples [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686656/does-this-shorthand-for-background-removes-the-other-attributes/8686661#8686661) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455465/why-cant-i-seem-to-use-background-clip/10455580#10455580)).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>A notable exception to this is `background-color`, because for any given box there is only one background color, which is always painted in the bottommost layer beneath the image in that layer. You can set `background-color` to a single value at a time anywhere in a rule, and it will not affect other layers.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with a :before pseudo-element.

http://codepen.io/lajlev/pen/DAyhn

```
.tile {
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: url('http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/tbbn3p08.png') no-repeat;

  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

.tile.last:before {
  background-color: green;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously there is not such thing, multiple backgrounds are set using `background-image` property which has no descendants like `background-image-1` etc.

However, you can override it using some Javascript