# How do I specify a single global background image using multiple background images?

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have several containers with multiple background images specified for each of them and separated by comma, where one of the background images is the same for every container.

```
.foo_1 {
  background-image: url(../img/01.png), url(../img/photo1.jpg);
}
.foo_2 {
  background-image: url(../img/01.png), url(../img/photo2.jpg);
}
.foo_3 {
  background-image: url(../img/01.png), url(../img/photo3.jpg);
}

.foo_1, .foo_2, .foo_3 {
  background-position: top left, center center;
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: auto, cover;
}
```

Is there any way to avoid repeating the image which is used in each class, while still keeping the structure of a background image and allowing for the same manipulation as of a normal background-image property ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to how the cascade works, it is not possible to specify multiple background layers in different rulesets without redeclaring the same background layer in each ruleset. See my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740266/how-can-i-override-only-the-second-image-in-a-multiple-background-image-declarat/14749243#14749243) for details:

> A comma-separated list of background layers counts as a single value for the purposes of the cascade, which is why your second `background` declaration completely overrides the first.
>
> While `background` is a shorthand for several other properties, it is not a shorthand for individual background layers, as they do not have their own properties. Since individual layer properties don't exist, you cannot use the cascade to override only certain layers while keeping the rest.

Answer (score -4):

you can  user  repeat-x  or repeat  property.

but  first of  all  you have need using Photoshop  make there  different images  for  each  container :

```
1. first_img.jpg ( img1.jpg + imga.jpg)

1. second_img.jpg ( img1.jpg + imgb.jpg)

3. third_img.jpg ( img1.jpg + imgc.jpg)


.foo_1 {
  background: url(../first_img.jpg) repeat-x or repeat ;
}
.foo_2 {
  background: url(../second_img.jpg) repeat-x or repeat ;
}
.foo3 {
  background: url(../third_img.jpg) repeat-x or repeat ;
}

Thanks.
```